# is plasma 5 supposed to work with lightdm?

Tags: lightdm, plasma-5

I just upgraded a Ubuntu 14.04 install to the 16.04 beta and thought I'd try out Plasma 5 now that it's available to me. I'm not running Kubuntu, but I figured an apt-get install plasma-desktop --install-recommends would do it, and when I logged out, Plasma was available as an option on the lightdm greeter. However, it had trouble rendering much (other than the log out menu) after logging in. Is Plasma pretty much SDDM only the way Gnome is GDM only now?